# Strange Intermittent WCF error casting IPermissions

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm currently trying to fix a WCF service error which I can't for the life of me work out any clue as to the cause...

The issue essentially is that it gets an InvalidCastException trying to turn things into IPrincipal objects (XmlDictionaryString & ClassDataContractCriticalHelper that I've seen in errors). Server-side it doesn't even hit our code, and the problem is we're only getting the issue very intermittently (2-3 times a week tops, with the API used multiple times per second) and given the amount of traffic hitting the service if we leave on full message logging we'll fill the production server hard drive in minutes.

The stack trace is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString' to type 'System.Security.IPermission'.    
Server stack trace:      at WriteOUROBJECTNAMEToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )     
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)     
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)    
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)     
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)     
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)     
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)     
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo part, Object graph)     
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameters(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters)     
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)     
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)     
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.WriteBodyToSignThenEncryptWithFragments(Stream stream, Boolean includeComments, String[] inclusivePrefixes, EncryptedData encryptedData, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     
at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.ApplyBodySecurity(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, IPrefixGenerator prefixGenerator)     
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionRequestChannelGeneric`1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)   
 Exception rethrown at [0]:      
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     
at OUR.CLIENT.ANONYMIZED.AddThing(ThingInfo data)
at OUR.CLIENT.ANONYMIZED.DoStuff()
```

Originally we had message security enabled, given the IPrincipal hint we swapped over to TransportWithMessageCredential and HTTPS encryption just to see if it worked but it got us nowhere. The config is:

```xml
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://www.anonymized.com"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="httpBindingBehaviour" name="Anonymized.Service.Implementation">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBindingConfig" name="httpBindingEndpoint" 
              contract="Anonymized.Service.Contract" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Anonymized" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="httpBindingBehaviour">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="160" maxConcurrentSessions="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="AnonymizedSqlMembershipProvider" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" roleProviderName="SqlRoleProvider">
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Does anyone have any theories, or even a hint where to look?

Comment: are you able to show the code ifrom `WriteOUROBJECTNAMEToXml` method

Comment: That's an autogenerated method in the .NET framework - it's not our code. I don't have any code for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of problem [DebugDiag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960) is perfect for.  You can configure a crash rule to log a crash dump for just this exception when it occurs.  There's a crash analysis script that comes with DebugDiag that might tell you enough so you can solve your problem.  Otherwise, you may have to debug it manually to find root cause.

Comment: Interesting, I might take a look at that... most diagnostic tools like that require a full-on application crash though right? WCF's handling this failure "gracefully" in that it's just returning a fault down to the client as opposed to bringing down the entire application pool - we're not even getting an error in the server's event logs or anything, WCF's just treating it like a bad request & throwing it away.

Comment: Not exactly.  You would configure your rule to catch 1st chance exceptions.  When a debugger is attached to a process, you can see (respond to) these 1st chance exceptions even though they are handled further up the call-stack.